# My python module does not see other modules

Tags: python, import, module

I have a folder with 2 files.

```
import_test.py
main.py.
```

Here is content of import_test.py:

```
def some_function():
        df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3],
                       'col_2': [1,2,3]})
        return df
```

Here is content of main.py:

```
import import_test
import pandas as pd
import importlib
importlib.reload(import_test)

import_test.some_function()
```

When I execute `import_test.some_function()`, I get back the following error:

```
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

I guess I can solve this problem by adding `import pandas as pd` in my `import_test.py` file, but this seems redundant to me, since `main.py` already has the import statement for pandas. Is there way to avoid the redundancy?

Comment: It might be a slight redundancy, but `pd` will still only be loaded once, since it will be located by `sys.modules`. You can verify this by checking the logs of `python -v` doing `import import_test; import pandas as pd;` versus `import pandas as pd; import import_test;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import modules where they are being used. When you use the `import` keyword, whatever you import is being bound to the current module's global namespace.

So it's not really a matter of your modules being unable to see each other, more that you've imported pandas in the wrong location. You can remove the pandas import from your main module if you import it where it's being used.

For what it's worth, C.Nivs is correct in saying that the module loader will only load pandas once even if you import it multiple times, so redundancy isn't much of an issue in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing `pd` into the function, and then supply `pd` to the function when calling it.

**import_test.py**:

```
def some_function(pd):
        df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [1,2,3],
                       'col_2': [1,2,3]})
        return df
```

**main.py**

```
import import_test
import pandas as pd
import importlib
importlib.reload(import_test)

import_test.some_function(pd)
```

Comment: While this may work, and I can't believe I've never thought of it. But this is not how you should use packages. You'll have to pass pd to every function where you need `pd`. Which is duplication as well. It's cleaner to import a package into modules wherever needed.